# How to apply a function to grouped rows between 2 dataframes?

Tags: r, dplyr, bioinformatics

I have 2 dataframes of genetic data, I am looking to run a hypergeometric testing function between the 2 (using the `GeneOverlap` package for the testing function) for all phenotypes across my 2 datasets. I’m trying to automate this process and store the results per each phenotype in a new data frame but I'm stuck on automating the function over all the phenotypes that are in both dataframes.

My datasets look like this:

Dataset1:

```
Gene      Gene_count   Phenotype
Gene1          5       Phenotype1
Gene1          5       Phenotype2
Gene2          3       Phenotype1
Gene3         16       Phenotype6
Gene3.        16       Phenotype2
Gene3         16       Phenotype1
```

Dataset2:

```
Gene    Gene_count     Phenotype
Gene1         10       Phenotype1
Gene1         10       Phenotype2
Gene4         4        Phenotype1
Gene2         17       Phenotype6
Gene6         3        Phenotype2
Gene7         2        Phenotype1
```

At the moment I run one hypergeometric test at a time, looking like this:

```
dataset1_pheno1 <- dataset1  %>%
  filter(str_detect(Phenotype, 'Phenotype1'))

dataset2_pheno1 <- dataset2  %>%
  filter(str_detect(Phenotype, 'Phenotype1'))

go.obj <- newGeneOverlap(dataset1_pheno1$Gene, 
                         dataset2_pheno1$Gene,
                         genome.size=1871)
go.obj <- testGeneOverlap(go.obj)
go.obj
```

I want to repeat this function for every phenotype in the 2 datasets, so far I’ve been trying to use the group_by() function in Dplyr and then trying to get a Geneoverlap function run inside that but I haven’t been able to get this working. What functions can I use to group by a column and row in 2 datasets to then run functions one group at a time?

Example input data:

```
library(GeneOverlap)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dataset1 <- structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene3.", 
"Gene3"), Gene_count = c(5L, 5L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 16L), Phenotype = c("Phenotype1", 
"Phenotype2", "Phenotype1", "Phenotype6", "Phenotype2", "Phenotype1"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))


dataset2 <- structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene4", "Gene2", "Gene6", 
"Gene7"), Gene_count = c(10L, 10L, 4L, 17L, 3L, 2L), Phenotype = c("Phenotype1", 
"Phenotype2", "Phenotype1", "Phenotype6", "Phenotype2", "Phenotype1"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `split` each dataset into lists by "Phenotype" and then use `Map` to run the tests against each set. But note that each dataset must have the same number of unique phenotypes, in the same order. In other words, `all(names(d1_split) == names(d2_split))` must be TRUE.

```
d1_split <- split(dataset1, dataset1$Phenotype)
d2_split <- split(dataset2, dataset2$Phenotype)

# this should be TRUE in order for Map to work correctly
all(names(d1_split) == names(d2_split))

tests <- Map(function(d1, d2) {
  go.obj <- newGeneOverlap(d1$Gene, d2$Gene, genome.size = 1871)
  return(testGeneOverlap(go.obj))
}, d1_split, d2_split)
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! I'm trying now to write the output into a file but I keep getting the same error of ```Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘structure("GeneOverlap", package = "GeneOverlap")’ to a data.frame``` - is there a way I can write the output into a file?

Comment: You may want to post that as a new question.